# Add class to elements one after another

Tags: jquery, html

I have DIVs with same class, initially hidden via CSS. When a button is clicked, I want to show them (add class) one after another.

Any hint / direction will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

```js
$(".add_another").click(function() {
  $(".task").addClass("taskshown"); 
  //Want to add "taskshown" class to the DIVs one after another
})
```

```css
.task {
  display:none;
}
.taskshown {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tasks">
    <div class = "task" id="task1">
        Task 1
    </div>
    <div class = "task" id="task2">
        Task 2
    </div>
    <div class = "task" id="task3">
        Task 3
    </div>
    <div class = "task" id="task4">
        Task 4
    </div>
    <div class = "task" id="task5">
        Task 5
    </div>
</div>

<a class = "add_another">Add another</a>
```

Comment: Changing `.add_alother` to `.add_another` seems to work.

Comment: Sorry about the typo. I have correct it. Madalin's code snippet works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `next()`

```
$(".add_another").click(function() {
       if($('.task:first').is('.taskshown')) {
          $(".taskshown").next().addClass("taskshown"); 
        } else {
          $('.task:first').addClass("taskshown"); 
        }
    });
```

demo:

```js
$(".add_another").click(function() {
  if ($('.task:first').is('.taskshown')) {
    $(".taskshown").next().addClass("taskshown");
  } else {
    $('.task:first').addClass("taskshown");
  }
});
```

```css
.task {
  display: none;
}
.taskshown {
  display: block;
}
.add_another {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tasks">
  <div class="task" id="task1">
    Task 1
  </div>
  <div class="task" id="task2">
    Task 2
  </div>
  <div class="task" id="task3">
    Task 3
  </div>
  <div class="task" id="task4">
    Task 4
  </div>
  <div class="task" id="task5">
    Task 5
  </div>
</div>

<a class="add_another">Add another</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTimeout()` within `$.each()`. Also edit your question to have the selector in jquery as `$('.another')` as it is a typo in your question.

```js
$(".add_another").click(function() {
        $(document).find('.task').each( function(k, v) {
    var el = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
        $(el).addClass("taskshown");
    }, k*1000);
        //Want to add "taskshown" class to the DIVs one after another
    })

    
   
});
```

```css
 .task {
        display:none;
    }
    .taskshown {
        display:block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tasks">
    <div class = "task" id="task1">
        Task 1
    </div>
    <div class = "task" id="task2">
        Task 2
    </div>
    <div class = "task" id="task3">
        Task 3
    </div>
    <div class = "task" id="task4">
        Task 4
    </div>
    <div class = "task" id="task5">
        Task 5
    </div>
</div>

<a class = "add_another">Add another</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this, plus Irfan's comment

```
$(".task").not('.taskshown').first().addClass("taskshown");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

".add_another" insted of ".add_alother"

```
$(".add_another").click(function() {
        $(".task").addClass("taskshown"); 
        //Want to add "taskshown" class to the DIVs one after another
    })
```